# is postdelayed within postdelayed dangerous?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to loop a short animation for an app and i found this solution or several of them in many sites and forums. However, the lead developer is telling me that this code will eventually crash the app and i should be using threading instead. Could anyone provide me a detailed explanation why this code would not be efficient to loop an animation? And if possible, does anyone know a way to use threads to accomplish what i stated in the previous lines. Thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {


    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            LoopImage(rocketAnimation,rocketImage,R.drawable.loops);

            runnable=this;

            h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: Ought to be fine.  `postDelayed` just puts an event containing the `Runnable` on the event queue.  Eventually the event handler gets it and runs the `Runnable`, which just adds a new event to the queue. Your lead developer might be concerned because the code looks recursive-ish. He probably fears it will use up the stack or clog the event queue.  It won't.

Answer (score 1):

You lead developer needs to educate himself a bit at first. Your code, albeit ugly, will work and I do not see any reason why it would eventually fail or crash the app. Anyway, I also see no much reason you would need that code at all as you should loop the animation using `android:repeatCount="infinite"` or `AnimationUtils` calls instead.

Comment: How is it ugly? and the code is using an animator list because we have different .png frames. And we have to repeat the animation on a delay since the word DELAY is in the code.

Comment: I'd bet you can get rid of `runnable=this;` thing. Also you can if you need animation paused between cycles, you can set it's last frame to simply last as long as your delay. So no code is needed expect for starting the animation

Comment: Wow. Very simple yet amazing. If you dont mind, could you provide me suggestions if wanted the animation to be done at random intervals?

Comment: Use AnimationListener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html and then in `onAnimationEnd` call `postDelayed`  Runnable starting your animation again. That's it.

Comment: Animation List uses AnimationDrawable and i dont think any of these methods is going to work with Animation. I tried casting Animation Drawable into an Animation and no luck. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hm, not sure what you talk about here